# Creating buttons from database table on runtime in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I want to create buttons from Database on runtime. 
For example I have a table lets say users. 
I need to create as many buttons as the user table contains.

The following code does that. But I have a problem, 
it gives me the last button only or it puts all buttons on top of other and I see only last button.

I need to get the buttons one next to other.

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
Bt: TButton;
i: Integer;
begin
Query1.First;
  while not Query1.Eof do
   begin
    i:=0;
    Bt := TButton.Create(Self);
    Bt.Caption := Query1.Fields[0].AsString;
    Bt.Parent := Self;
    Bt.Height := 23;
    Bt.Width := 100;
    Bt.Left := 10;
    Bt.Top := 10 + i * 25;

    i:= i+1;
    Query1.Next;
  end;
end;
```

what should I change or add?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You reset the `i` counter with every loop iteration. Initialize it once before you enter the loop:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;  
  Bt: TButton;  
begin
  Query1.First;
  i := 0; // initialize the counter before you enter the loop
  while not Query1.Eof do
  begin
    Bt := TButton.Create(Self);
    Bt.Caption := Query1.Fields[0].AsString;
    Bt.Parent := Self;
    Bt.Height := 23;
    Bt.Width := 100;
    Bt.Left := 10;
    Bt.Top := 10 + i * 25;
    i := i + 1;
    Query1.Next;
  end;
end;
```